# mixing foldr with OR in Haskell (laziness?)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation, evaluation, declarative

How can this function return true?

```
foldr (||) False [True,undefined] 

=> True
```

The first fold looks like this:

```
undefined || True
```

, which should return an error

So im guessing haskell gives priority to the lazyness of the OR function over doing the folds step by step. Finds a `True` on the way and returns that before starting the fold

Is this correct? In that case, does haskell always give priority to a lazy function over the non lazy ones? I believe that is the definition for being lazy but it seems like that can change the answer to make it wrong

Comment: Why do you believe the first fold looks like `undefined || True`? Because that is incorrect, so if you can explain why you believe that, we may be able to point to the error in your reasoning that led to that conclusion.

Comment: @DanielWagner it would be the first use of `(||)` evaluated if `foldr` actually folded from the right, the way it often does in strict languages.

Comment: @Carl One could argue that `foldr` does fold from the right, denotationally. Its "first" fold is `undefined || False` which is `undefined`. The "second" is `True || undefined` which is `True` since OR is lazy (as it would also be in Java,C,etc.).

Comment: Comparing "folds from the right" to "iterates right-to-left" is a sign that you're still thinking too imperatively. "folds from the right" is a statement about associativity, nothing more.

Comment: @Carl It does fold from the right in some sense; but in that sense, the "first" fold is actually `undefined || False`, not `undefined || True`! This does (would) become `undefined`, as you observed, but unlike in a lazy language, it turns out that just because some part of the computation has `undefined` doesn't mean the whole thing is `undefined`...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the definition of `foldr`,

```
foldr (||) False [True,undefined]
=
True || foldr (||) False [undefined]
```

According to the definition of `(||)`,

```
True || _ = True
```

so there's no need to know the value of the right hand expression to know the answer.

`foldr` does *not* do steps on its own. The process is driven by the demands of the reducer function.

*edit:* Nothing funny's going on. Each evaluation step is straightforwardly done according to the definitions involved.